# can't do any thing inside window.onload event

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

this code was working before but somehow stop of running

i try to track the problem

**_messages.blade.php**

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
<script>
    console.log(1) // first test
    window.onload = function () {
        console.log(2) // second test
        toast.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: "{{ session('success') }}",
            timer: 3000,
            timerProgressBar: true
        })
    }
</script>
@endif
```

the problem is in `console.log(2)` didn't print i don't know what happen for this weird error

**master.blade.php**

```
<body>
    @include('layouts.user._header')
    @include('layouts.user._navbar')
    @include('layouts.user._messages')

    @yield('content')

    @include('layouts.user._footer')

    <!-- ============================= -->
    <script>
        const baseData = {
            url: '{{ url('/') }}',
            lang: '{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() }}',
            currency: '@lang("user.currency")',
        }
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/owl.carousel.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/sweetalert.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/custom.js') }}"></script>
    @yield('script')
</body>
```

> there is not error in the console

Comment: can you move it out of `@if(session()->has('success'))`? if it is session success, then did your window already finish "onload" already so you are setting it too late?

Comment: But the toast method works before like this but now didn't work and i try to clear cach and nothing happens

Comment: can you give it a try and move it out and see what happens?

Comment: I try it it gives me Toast is undefined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It fixed when i move the `_messages.balde.php` at the bottom after all of `scripts`
and remove `onload` method

**_messages.blade.php**

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
<script>
        toast.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: "{{ session('success') }}",
            timer: 3000,
            timerProgressBar: true
        })

</script>
@endif
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<body>
    @include('layouts.user._header')
    @include('layouts.user._navbar')

    @yield('content')

    @include('layouts.user._footer')

    <!-- ============================= -->
    <script>
        const baseData = {
            url: '{{ url('/') }}',
            lang: '{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() }}',
            currency: '@lang("user.currency")',
        }
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/owl.carousel.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/sweetalert.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('user/js/custom.js') }}"></script>
    @include('layouts.user._messages')
    @yield('script')
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

give `onload="yourFunction()"` to body tag 
like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i try it to but nothing happens i don't know what happen it made me crazy :(